# Ransack Searching Full Name with White Spaces

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I have a user model with the fields

```
:first_name 
:last_name
```

I wanna a single search box that says full_name where the user can search for

```
John Doe
```

in my user.rb

```
ransacker :full_name do |parent|
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('concat_ws', [' ',    parent.table[:first_name], parent.table[:last_name]])
end
```

in my views i have

```
= f.text_field :full_name_cont, placeholder: 'full name'
```

however when a user creates a name with a space in front of it

```
 first_name: 'John'
 last_name: ' Doe'
```

and i search for

```
 'John Doe'
 - no results
```

but if i search for

```
  'John  Doe' (two spaces in between)
   - 'John Doe'
```

How can i prevent this from happening

I know ideally i would want to sanitize the data before creating by stripping white spaces....but what would be the most unobtrusive way of getting around this bug.

Thanks